# Outlook add-in event-based with OfficeRuntime.auth

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, add-in

I'm new to this topic, but I've taken some time to understand some things.

I would like to know how I get a token from an event, I read that OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken() can be used but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks for your help.

I hope get the token when the event onMessageComposeHandler is called.
I am on outlook windows.

Comment: Can you share more about why getAccessToken() doesn't work for you? What error message did you get and how did you use it?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I am on the same boat. My add-in works on OWA but trying to debug it on the desktop (using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch?tabs=windows)) the function just does not return. I see no error message.

Comment: I also added the .well-known/microsoft-officeaddins-allowed.json file as [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-sso-in-event-based-activation) says.